# Dynamic push --tag on Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, npm, git-push, git-tag

Sorry to disturb because I'm quite new on the subject and I'm learning.

I'd like to run a Jenkins build of my clients but I'm having a problem. I'm trinyg to build a job that is going  to create a tag of my Angular Application.

I use npm-version to create the bump's version and also git's tag. It should be working but I still have to create a git push.

if I use `git push --tags` in the shell while building, I'm having this error  :

[image: It's the error I'm getting I'm not allowed to show pictures here]

so then I tried :

`git push && git push --tags`

it doesn't work because it asks for my credentials.

What I'm looking for :

- Push the bumped version of the remote branch I specified in my builds parameters
- Push the tag created in remote

So, I either need to :

- Find a way to put my git's credentials in the shell script
- Find a way to use Git public for the push's tag AND the branch I had initially in my parameters.

I've come across StackOverflow on couple pages and I had one that told me I could do everything in one command but as I'm being stupid I didn't save the link and I strangely can't find it back.

If you guys can help me find back this solution that will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for doing an unattended push with Git:

- use SSH instead of HTTP(S) - this is the preferred solution
- augment the remote url with username/password, e.g. `git push --tags https://<username>:<password>@hostname.com`. NB: this carries a certain security risk if the password ends up in your build log, or if it's specified directly in your build parameters.
- (in Jenkins) reuse the password specified for the cloning in a separate step, see examples here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335?focusedCommentId=269000&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel
- store credentials in a credential helper (since it messes with the Jenkins' built in Git cloning functionality, you'd need to activate this right before doing your git operation, then revert it; e.g. `git config credentials.helper 'store --file ./.my-credentials'`, `echo https://user:pass@example.com > ./my-credentials`). See previous remark about the danger of the password getting logged, etc; also you'd need to make sure your workspace is deleted after each build, or your credentials will be sitting on the build server plaintext. Also see here for an example of creating your own credential helper script if you need to inject custom logic: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage#_a_custom_credential_cache

Comment: First of all, Those methods have to be tested. I'll check all of them.

Are you sure that the SSH auth will get rid of push tag problem with the double auth required ?

Comment: @user1980933, as long as you've set up the correct SSH key, the push will succeed without user authentication

Comment: Looks like my client just wants to push the tags and then push the branch, yet I don't know how to do it on jenkins. :(

Comment: @user1980933, I'm afraid "I don't know how" is too vague for anyone to be able to help you very much. Your initial question suggests you're able to run git in a shell on Jenkins, so just use an SSH format remote instead of HTTPS: for example, if your repo is in Github, use git push git@github.com:<account>/<repo>.git instead of git push https:/ /github.com/<account>/<repo>.git